# 400 BAD REQUEST. (Ajax Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ajax

Читал по инструкциям, примерам и похожим запросам и всё равно ошибка остаётся.

Сервер локальный.

HTML:

```
<form action=""  method="POST" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="dragon">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#form").on('submit', function(){
  var data = {
    val: $('#form input').val() ,
    action: 'udapte_data'
  } 

  $.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data), 
  }) 
})
```

PHP:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_udapte_data', 'udapte_data' ); 
 
function udapte_data(){
    update_user_meta(1, 'dragon', $_POST('dragon'));
 
    die; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не переопределяйте `contentType`

JS:

```
jQuery("#form").on('submit', function (event) {

     event.preventDefault();

     var data = {
         action: 'udapte_data',
         val: jQuery('#form input').val()
     }

     jQuery.ajax({
         url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
         type: 'POST',
         data: data,
     })
})
```

PHP:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_udapte_data', 'udapte_data_cb' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_udapte_data', 'udapte_data_cb' );

function udapte_data_cb(){
    update_user_meta(1, 'dragon', $_POST['val']);
 
    die(); 
}
```

Либо если хотите отправлять JSON, вручную обрабатывайте данные на стороне сервера. Тут можно почитать ответы по этой теме
[тема1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49657176/wordpress-ajax-cant-use-post-cant-pass-object)
[тема2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295080/ajax-call-with-contenttype-application-json-not-working)

Comment: @KAGGDesign Почему не о том, попробуйте добавить contentType и у вас так же будет выдавать 400 ошибку т.к. action не обрабатывается, а для залогиненых пользователей в моем ответе хук тоже добавлен.

Comment: Да, всё правильно в вашем ответе. Проблема в том, что при json в POST отсутствует action, и admin-ajax.php возвращает 400.

Comment: Поправил опечатку: `$_POST['val']` - квадратные скобки нужны.